# How to open file in script directory when script runs from Cron Job

Tags: python, cron

I have this in my crontab:

```
31 9 * * *  /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/price/price.py > /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/price/stdout.log 2>&1 &
```

The problem is that Python  can't find any of the files that use just filenames.

How should I open files in Python so they work in cron.

stdout.log have one line from logger:

```
2020-07-30 09:31:01,776 - price_history - ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'init.sql'
```

My code have just `open('init.sql').read()`

Comment: You need to *cd* in the proper directory: `31 9 * * *  cd /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/price && /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/price/price.py > /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/price/stdout.log 2>&1 &`

Comment: @SergeBallesta that works, thanks. You code don't need the full path after cd though.

Comment: You need to modify your code to not assume the files being opened are all in the current working directory by using absolute path names. You can extract the directory from the path of current script that's running from the built-in `__file__` variable. Alternatively you can change the current working directory to be that folder so the files will be found without full paths.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @martineau solution:

```
def chwd():
    script = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    path = os.path.dirname(script)
    os.chdir(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chwd()
```